# armstrong number alternative output

Tags: python

```
lower = int(input())
upper = int(input())

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
   order = len(str(num))
   sum = 0
   temp = num
   while temp > 0:
       digit = temp % 10
       sum += digit ** order
       temp //= 10

   if num == sum:
       print(num,end = " ")
```

I wrote a program to get all the Armstrong numbers between the acquired range.
Here I want to print an output -1 if there is no Armstrong number present within the range.

When I try to give a else condition with print output as -1, it prints -1 for every iterated value.
How should I print -1 only once if there is no Armstrong number present?

Comment: Please [edit] to show the code you are actually asking about. Where do you put the `else:`?

Answer (score 0):

```python
lower = int(input())
upper = int(input())

# use boolean(as flag) or integer(0 as a counter)
getAny = False

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    order = len(str(num))
    sum = 0
    temp = num
    while temp > 0:
        digit = temp % 10
        sum += digit ** order
        temp //= 10

    if num == sum:
        # when got positive response, toggle or increment value
        getAny = True
        print(num,end = " ")

# check if it's till false or 0, means not get any number
if not getAny:
    print(-1)
```